# Unable to connect to Salesforce using RestAPI: INVALID SESSION

Tags: android, rest, salesforce

Hi i am trying to connect to Salesforce with the Rest API and i want to retrieve sObjects..Implementing  as below

```
void getsObjects() throws IOException {


    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://na14.salesforce.com/services/data/v24.0/sobjects");

    try {


        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("X-HostCommonName", "ap1.salesforce.com"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("X-PrettyPrint", "1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Host", "ap1.salesforce.com"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("X-Target-URI", "https://ap1.salesforce.com"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Type", "application/json"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Connection", "Keep-Alive"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization", "00D90000000qUEp!AQQAQNnuPZqEX2oqAkeQLmvq.qsBfKIMa3GCJvE7atLv2Cjy94YZn5ezRH0bosXTFthnoMNt.WpDturXB1Ijxxxxxxxxxx"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println("Final response"+result);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    }
```

even if i am passing the the Authorization key , it is giving INVALID SESSION error

```
12-11 14:50:18.108: W/DefaultRequestDirector(27014): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {token=WWW-Authenticate: Token}


12-11 14:50:18.498: I/System.out(27014): Final response[{"errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID","message":"Session expired or invalid"}]
```

I am trying to connect to it from 2 days but no luck, can someone point me right direction, how to make rest calls.

Comment: the code seems good, is the key valid?

Comment: yeah i guess so, how to check the key valid or not

Comment: try to generate a new key and see if you still get the same error. The message you get is very clear though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Authorization header should take the form `Authorization: Bearer {sessionId}` whereas you have `Authorization:{sessionId}`
2. You `nameValuePairs` appears to contains http headers, but you're not creating headers, you're passing them to setEntity, which sets the http body payload, not the headers.
3. You're creating a bunch of standard headers (like Host) which don't align with the actual url, and these aren't needed anyway.

try something like

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://na14.salesforce.com/services/data/v24.0/sobjects");
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization" , "Bearer " + sessionId)
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("someJson", "UTF-8");
entity.setCotnentType("application/json");
httpPost.setEntity(entity)
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println("Final response"+result);
```

You might also want to checkout the [Force.com Android SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android) which has a bunch of helpers for accessing the API.

Comment: @Superfella, hi thankyou for the answer, also i have a query on seesion id, i using the template app provided as sample in SF SDK, for login, i am gettin Authtoken and refreshtocken, but i could not see sessionid, how should i get the session id.

Comment: auth token is the same as a session id.